# Assigning values to std::array of std::optional objects

Tags: c++, c++17, stdarray, stdoptional

I am trying to fill a std::array of std::optional objects as below.

```
class MyClass
{
   private:
    int distance;
    MyClass(int x, int y);

   friend class MasterClass;
};

MyClass::MyClass(int x, int y)
{
  distance = x+y;
}

class MasterClass
{
  public:
  MasterClass(std::array<std::optional<int>,5> xs, std::array<std::optional<int>,5> ys);
  
  private:
  std::array<std::optional<MyClass>, 5> myclassarray{};

};

MasterClass::MasterClass(std::array<std::optional<int>,5> xs, std::array<std::optional<int>,5> ys)
 {
     for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
     {
         myclassarray[i].emplace(new  MyClass(*xs[i], *ys[i])); //---(1)
     }

 }
```

From the line commented with (1) above, I get the following error,

```
error: no matching function for call to std::optional<MyClass>::emplace(MyClass&)
```

I also tried replacing the same line with

```
 myclassarray[i] = new  MyClass(*xs[i], *ys[i]) ; //---(2)
```

This will give me

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::array<std::optional<MyClass>,5>::value_type’ {aka ‘std::optional<MyClass>’} and ‘MyClass*’)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry, updated the question as there was a typo in the masterclass constructor. Yes. I need fixed size arrays here.

Comment: Okay, How do I assign an object to array element here?

Comment: Just remove `new`

Comment: With smart pointers, you never need to use `new` in modern C++ code. There is `make_shared` and `make_unique`. There is even a `make_optional`, but that is not needed in your code.

Comment: @jxh Before C++20 you had to use `new` if you wanted it default-initialized. Fortunately `make_unique_for_overwrite` arrived in C++20.

Comment: @TedLyngmo [Let's chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240739/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70586376-assigning-values-to-stdarray-of-stdo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like maybe you are coming from Java, or C#. When you assign a value in c++, it is rare that you will use `new`. The issue is, that you are basically doing this:

```
std::optional<MyClass> o = new MyClass();
```

o is of type, `std::optional<MyClass>` and `new My Class()` is of type `MyClass *`. You can see from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D) that there is no operation that converts a pointer to an object to an optional of an object. Lets take this back to basics, what we want to do is something like:

```
std::optional<int> o; // defaults to std::nullopt
o = value; // We set it with some value.
```

And actually this is all there is to it. So lets expand to an array:

```
std::array<std::optional<int>, 5> a; // An array with 5 optional, all are std::nullopt
a[2] = value; // Set the optional at position 2 to a value.
```

And this extends easily to your example:

```
for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
     myclassarray[i] = MyClass(*xs[i], *ys[i]));
}
```

Just be careful with this bit:

```
*xs[i], *ys[i]
```

because from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*):

> The behavior is undefined if *this does not contain a value.

Which will cause you much grief if this is the case.

Comment: The `emplace` version would then be: `myclassarray[i].emplace(*xs[i], *ys[i]);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo it would, but there is basically no benefit to emplace here, and i think the assignment is much more clear.

Comment: Agree! I just thought it was worth mentioning the proper way to use `emplace` since OP started out with it